# Why is this PHP login script not working?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, authentication

I want the user to login to his account from this login page. It should perform different actions based on whether the user has left the fields empty, or login criteria is not correct or the details are correct. But it keeps on giving this response that "Login unsuccessful, please try again." Can someone help me in solving this problem?

```
<?php
include_once("db_con.php");
if(isset($_POST['e'])) {
$e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_con, $_POST['e']);
$p = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_con, $_POST['p']);
$p_hash = password_hash($p, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
if($e == "" || $p == ""){
    echo "login_failed";
    exit();
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email='$e' LIMIT 
1";
    $login_query = mysqli_query($db_con, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($login_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $db_id = $row["id"];
    $db_username = $row["username"];
    $db_pass_str = $row["password"];
    if($p_hash != $db_pass_str){
        echo "login_failed";
        exit();
    }
        else {
        // CREATE THEIR SESSIONS AND COOKIES

        $user_closed_query = mysqli_query($db_con, "SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE email='$e' AND user_closed='yes'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($user_closed_query)) {
            $account_reopen = mysql_query($db_con, "UPDATE users SET 
user_closed='no' WHERE email='$e'");
        }

        $_SESSION['userid'] = $db_id;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $db_username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $db_pass_str;
        setcookie("id", $db_id, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
        setcookie("user", $db_username, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", 
"", TRUE);
        setcookie("pass", $db_pass_str, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", 
"", TRUE); 
        // UPDATE THEIR "IP" AND "LASTLOGIN" FIELDS
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET lastlogin=now() WHERE 
username='$db_username' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_con, $sql);
        echo $db_username;
        exit();
    }
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
    function login(){
        var e = document.getElementById("log_email");
        var p = document.getElementById("log_password");
        if(e == "" || p == ""){
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form 
data";
} else {
    document.getElementById("login_button").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Please wait...";
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", "login.php", true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form- 
urlencoded");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            if(ajax.responseText == "login_failed"){
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Login 
unsuccessful, please try again.";
                document.getElementById("login_button").disabled = false;
            } else {
                window.location = "index.php?u="+ajax.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send("e="+e+"&p="+p);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<h3>Log In Here</h3>
<!-- LOGIN FORM -->
<form id="loginform" onsubmit="return false;">
<div>Email Address:</div>
<input type="text" id="log_email" name="log_email" maxlength="88">
<div>Password:</div>
<input type="password" id="log_password" name="log_password" 
maxlength="100">
<br /><br />
<button id="login_button" onclick="login()">Log In</button> 
<span id="status"></span>
<a href="#">Forgot Your Password?</a>
</form>
<!-- LOGIN FORM -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!
Even if I enter the correct email and password, the page responses that login unsuccessful. I want it to go to index.php when user signs in successfully. 
Here is the image:-
[This is the screenshot of what happens every time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8vjT.png)

Comment: You need to put more effort into this question.  Where does it break? We need details on how it is not working.

Comment: `var e = document.getElementById("log_email");
        var p = document.getElementById("log_password");
        if(e == "" || p == ""){` <-- WRONG, a DOM element reference is never going to equal an empty string.

Comment: simple debugging will show you what e and p are.... console.log("e", e); console.log("p", p);

Comment: What should I use to check for empty fields then?

Comment: The value.... .

Comment: as in `var e = document.getElementById("log_email").value;`

Answer (score 2):

You are using `passwod_hash()` to hash the password, but you aren't using `password_verify()` to verify it.

Look at the docs! http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: How odd to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` *before* hashing the password too ;)

Comment: I would keep that in mind that too from now on! Thanks!

Comment: glad I could help! :-D

Comment: can you mark this as the correct answer please? :-D